# Almost Surely convergence with Bernoulli

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf, borel-cantelli-lemmas

How can I demonstrate that a  sequence of Bernoulli Random Variables Xn with parameter $\frac1{2n^2}$ converges almost surely to some random variable X?
I know that $X_n$ takes the value $1$ with Probability $\frac1{2n^2}$ and $0$ with probability $1-\frac1{2n^2}$. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are the $X_n$ independent?

Comment: And if we substitute (1/n) as a parameter? Does it turn out the same result for the almost sure convergence?

Comment: @JohnDawkins Does it matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It will converge a.s. to the zero (constant) random variable. This is a simple application of the Borel-Cantelli lemma.

Let $A_n$ be the event that $X_n=1$. Then $\mathrm{Pr}(A_n) = \frac{1}{2n^2}$, which is summable. Hence by the Borel-Cantelli lemma, with probability one, only finitely many of the $A_n$ will occur. Note that independence of $X_n$ is not assumed.

This means that for some $N$, $X_n = 0$ for all $n>N$ a.s., i.e. $X_n \to 0$ a.s.